# Sending JSON via Jquery AJAX call to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I am trying to pass a JSON array from jquery ajax call to a php file and in php file, I am writing the received data to a file. My code :

```
var contacts = [{"address":[],"phone":[],"last_name":"abc","email":[{"address":"test@yahoo.com","type":null,"selected":true}],"first_name":"Test"}];
    $.ajax({
    url: 'handler.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:  { 'json': JSON.stringify(contacts) } ,
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

And php code :

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
    $response = json_decode($json);

$file = fopen('test.txt','w+');
    fwrite($file, $response);
    fclose($file);

echo "Done";
```

It is not writing the json data into the file i.e. File is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode` takes a JSON string, and parses it into an object (or associative array). Since you want to write it to a file, you don't need to parse it first (one writes strings to files, not objects).

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
file_put_contents('text.txt', $json)
```